# When will tf.print ACTUALLY WORK as expected (i.e. print the values of tensors and variables)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

First of all, I am using TensorFlow 2.0 and I only care about this version or higher (and I am already caring too much for such a piece of software that only produces headaches).

The [TensorFlow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/print) of `tf.print` says

> Print the specified inputs.

and then

> A TensorFlow operator that prints the specified inputs to a desired output stream or logging level. The inputs may be
>
> - **dense** or
> - **sparse Tensors**,
> - **primitive python objects**,
> - **data structures that contain tensors**, and
> - **printable Python objects**.
>
> Printed tensors will recursively show the first and last elements of each dimension to summarize.

This is all very nice, but I still don't get where `tf.print` will ACTUALLY WORK (i.e. print the VALUES of variables and tensors) in my code. Of course, needless to say, I couldn't care less about the symbolic representations of tensors, variables or whatever. Whenever I try to use `tf.print`, I want to see the VALUES (real numbers, vectors or matrices).

I've tried to use `tf.print` in multiple cases and in multiple places, e.g.

- in a method that is called from the `__init__` method of a custom layer that is called during model building (so before compiling the model) in order to print the value of a tensor (at least, this is what the `type(my_var)` returns, i.e. it returns `<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>`), but nothing is printed. If I try to add `@tf.function` (I still don't get the usage of this function!), nothing changes. According to the documentation above `tf.print` is supposed to print tensors, my variable is a tensor and TensorFlow decides to ignore my call, and then one wonders why did I decide to use TF? Why?

  Also, I am using TF 2.0 and, even if I don't use the decorator `@tf.function`, `print(tf.executing_eagerly())` prints False, which is really what I was expecting.
- in a custom loss function, where a similar behaviour happens (i.e. sometimes something is printed, sometimes it is not, sometimes I try to add the decorator `@tf.function` to the custom loss function and see if something changes, but nothing changes, or maybe yes).

Ok, so, as you can see, I have no idea where `tf.print` will do what I want, i.e. I want to see the values of tensors. If something is a tensor, it must have a value. Similarly for variables.

So, when will `tf.print` ACTUALLY PRINT THE VALUES OF TENSORS?

I am looking for answers that say e.g., "`tf.print` will NEVER work" or "it will only work if you are dreaming". Apart from the jokes and sarcasm, I am really looking for answers that tell me exactly in which places of my code or which stages of developing a model with TF `tf.print`  will actually do what it is supposed to do. Please, don't tell me that `tf.print` will work when the input is a tensor!!

Comment: Hi, would you please provide a minimal example? I tried your first point, create a custom layer, tf.print the variable created via `self.add_weight` and everything works as expected.

Comment: @Richard_wth In my answer, I say `type(my_var)`  it returns `<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>`. Does your variable also return that? I don't think so, it probably returns `ResourceVariable`.

Comment: Yes, it returns `ResourceVariable`.

Comment: @Richard_wth Then try to print something that is a tensor instead to see if you observe the same behaviour.

Comment: In Eager mode (where `tf.executing_eagerly()` returns True), `tf.print(some_tensor)` gave the values of that tensor in my case. When I explicitly disabled the Eager mode, according to [tf.print documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/print), I added `tf.control_dependencies` to enforce `tf.print` to run, which also gave me the values of that tensor.

Comment: @Richard_wth As I say in my post above, I am using TF 2.1, so eager mode should be enabled by default everywhere. Which version of TF are you using? Also, you say "where `tf.executing_eagerly()` returns True", but does it return true inside a method of a custom layer for you? Where are you trying to print the tensor?

Comment: I am using TF 2.2rc3 on Colab. Yes, the eager mode is enabled by default everywhere (`tf.executing_eagerly()` returns true both inside a method of a custom layer and outside any function/class, as I have tried). I just noticed that you opened [an issue on Github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/38775) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61355474/why-does-tf-executing-eagerly-return-false-in-tensorflow-2-although-i-am-not) about `tf.executing_eagerly` inside `tfp.layers.DenseFlipout`, which I somehow read earlier today. Sorry, it also returns True in my case.

Comment: @Richard_wth Try to use it inside a custom layer that inherits from `tfp.layers.DenseFlipout` and try to use TensorFlow 2.1. I want to understand if this is TF 2.1 issue or what.

Comment: I tried TF v2.1 (TF probability v0.9) and your example in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61355474/why-does-tf-executing-eagerly-return-false-in-tensorflow-2-although-i-am-not), `tf.executing_eagerly` returned True.

Comment: @Richard_wth Hm, that's very very strange!! What could cause `tf.executing_eagerly` to return False? I have actually asked a question about this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61355474/3924118.

Comment: @Richard_wth Yes? Check this out: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/38775 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/61355474/3924118 where `tf.executing_eagerly` returns `False`.

Comment: Yes, I can reproduce the issue at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/38775, but even in this case, `tf.print('inputs', tf.convert_to_tensor(inputs))` returns the values of a tensor.... I'll read more on `tf.executing_eagerly() -> False`.

Answer (score 0):

`tf.print` works almost in every case.

Mentioned below is the code which demonstrates that `tf.print` works as expected inside `init` Method of `Custom Layer` and inside a `Method` called from `init` Method of a `Custom Layer`.

```
import tensorflow as tf

class MyLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, units, **kwargs): 
        self.units = units
        tf.print('units', tf.convert_to_tensor(units)) # Inside init method
        self.call(10) # Method called from init Method
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
    def call(self, inputs):        
        tf.print('inputs', tf.convert_to_tensor(inputs)) #Inside Method of Custom Layer
        return inputs


def get_model():
    inp = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,))
    out = MyLayer(8)(inp)
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inp, outputs=out)
    #model.summary()
    return model


def train():
    model = get_model()
    model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="mae")
    x_train = [2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 6]
    y_train = [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
    model.fit(x_train, y_train)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    train()
```

Output of the `tf.print` statements used in the code above is shown below:

```
units 8

inputs 10

inputs [[2]
 [6]
 [3]
 [2]
 [1]
 [4]]
```

If you see that `tf.print` is not working as expected in any other case, please share the reproducible code so that the `Tensorflow Community` can take a look.