# Why does tf.executing_eagerly() return False in TensorFlow 2?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-probability

Let me explain my set up. I am using TensorFlow 2.1, the Keras version shipped with TF, and TensorFlow Probability 0.9.

I have a function `get_model` that creates (with the functional API) and returns a model using Keras and custom layers. In the `__init__` method of these custom layers `A`, I call a method `A.m`, which executes the statement `print(tf.executing_eagerly())`, but it returns `False`. Why?

To be more precise, this is roughly my setup

```
def get_model():
    inp = Input(...)
    x = A(...)(inp) 
    x = A(...)(x)
    ...
    model = Model(inp, out)
    model.compile(...)
    return model

class A(tfp.layers.DenseFlipout): # TensorFlow Probability
    def __init__(...):
        self.m()

    def m(self): 
        print(tf.executing_eagerly()) # Prints False
```

The documentation of [`tf.executing_eagerly`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/executing_eagerly) says

> Eager execution is enabled by default and this API returns True in most of cases. However, this API might return False in the following use cases.
>
> - Executing inside `tf.function`, unless under `tf.init_scope` or `tf.config.experimental_run_functions_eagerly(True)` is previously called.
> - Executing inside a transformation function for `tf.dataset`.
> - `tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()` is called.

But these cases are not my case, so `tf.executing_eagerly()` should return `True` in my case, but no. Why?

Here's a simple complete example (in TF 2.1) that illustrates the problem.

```
import tensorflow as tf


class MyLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def call(self, inputs):
        tf.print("tf.executing_eagerly() =", tf.executing_eagerly())
        return inputs


def get_model():
    inp = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,))
    out = MyLayer(8)(inp)
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inp, outputs=out)
    model.summary()
    return model


def train():
    model = get_model()
    model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="mae")
    x_train = [2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 6]
    y_train = [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
    model.fit(x_train, y_train)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    train()
```

This example prints `tf.executing_eagerly() = False`.

See [the related Github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/38775).

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, when an input to a custom layer is symbolic input, then the layer is executed in graph (non-eager) mode. However, if your input to the custom layer is an eager tensor (as in the following example #1, then the custom layer is executed in the eager mode. So your model's output `tf.executing_eagerly() = False` is expected.

Example #1

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers


class Linear(layers.Layer):

  def __init__(self, units=32, input_dim=32):
    super(Linear, self).__init__()
    w_init = tf.random_normal_initializer()
    self.w = tf.Variable(initial_value=w_init(shape=(input_dim, units),
                                              dtype='float32'),
                         trainable=True)
    b_init = tf.zeros_initializer()
    self.b = tf.Variable(initial_value=b_init(shape=(units,),
                                              dtype='float32'),
                         trainable=True)

  def call(self, inputs):
    print("tf.executing_eagerly() =", tf.executing_eagerly())
    return tf.matmul(inputs, self.w) + self.b

x = tf.ones((1, 2)) # returns tf.executing_eagerly() = True
#x = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(2,)) #tf.executing_eagerly() = False
linear_layer = Linear(4, 2)
y = linear_layer(x)
print(y) 
#output in graph mode: Tensor("linear_9/Identity:0", shape=(None, 4), dtype=float32)
#output in Eager mode: tf.Tensor([[-0.03011466  0.02563028  0.01234017  0.02272708]], shape=(1, 4), dtype=float32)
```

Here is another example with Keras functional API where custom layer was used (similar to you). This model is executed in graph mode and prints `tf.executing_eagerly() = False` as in your case.

```
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
class CustomDense(layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self, units=32):
    super(CustomDense, self).__init__()
    self.units = units

  def build(self, input_shape):
    self.w = self.add_weight(shape=(input_shape[-1], self.units),
                             initializer='random_normal',
                             trainable=True)
    self.b = self.add_weight(shape=(self.units,),
                             initializer='random_normal',
                             trainable=True)

  def call(self, inputs):
    print("tf.executing_eagerly() =", tf.executing_eagerly())
    return tf.matmul(inputs, self.w) + self.b


inputs = keras.Input((4,))
outputs = CustomDense(10)(inputs)

model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be running in a Colab. If so, try the following immediately after importing Tensorflow:

```
tf.compat.v1.enable_v2_behavior()
```

More generally, check the docs at https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/executing_eagerly for more information on eager execution.